# Winter is coming

Tags: cipher, seasonal

Holidays aren't far, I hope.

[image]

Source: myself

Comment: I know the answer but I don't know how to get there xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Cipher is a 3x3 rectangle (with open outer borders, think #) with 3 letters in each block, left to right in alphabetical order.
> Dot indicates which letter to use; first, second or third.
>
> Answer is as others have figured out: MERRY CHRISTMAS
>
> [image: depicturing the cypher]

Edit: Seems i got ninja'ed

Comment: I was waiting for the grid, nice job :)

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the puzzle is.......:

> [image]

Comment: Well done, correct answer and order of the letters. I gave the tick to the guy that answered second because he figured out how I created the puzzle.

Comment: @KonstantinPfennig had the most complete answer, so they definitely deserve the tick! Thanks for the puzzle

Answer (score -1):

With some guesswork and comparing letters it is easy to see that the cipher spells

> Merry christmas

And the same to you too.

Comment: I agree but I think the point is to figure out why